# SSIS execution with connection to blob storage by AccountKey

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

From this afternoon, we face some issues on several environments to execute SSIS managed by Azure Data Factory.

The SSIS package needs access to blob storage, done so by using a connection string with `AccountKey`.

We get now a systemic error:

```
{
  "SsisDBOperationGuid": "XXXXXXXXXX",
  "SsisDBOperationId": XX,
  "OperationErrorMessages": "6/26/2019 4:08:08 PM +00:00 : LVL0_XXX_Main:Error: Property \"AccountKey\" is not specified.\n6/26/2019 4:08:08 PM +00:00 : LVL0_XXX_Main:Error: Connection \"CN_AzureBlobStorage_MasterData\" failed validation.\r\n\n",
  "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "XXXX-MD-SSIS-IntegrationRuntime (West Europe)",
  "executionDuration": 21558
}
```

Any idea about it ?

Thank you

Comment: issue resolved by itself. Probably an Azure platform bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have contacted microsoft, yesterday they did a security update that cause that issue. A few minutes ago, they did a rollout, so all goes fine now.

Comment: That should rather be a comment. If you want to keep it as answer you should at least add a link to a tracked issue that documents the solution.